# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' updated

Tags: sql, database

The purpose of the query is to check in certain rows for incorrect information. The rows with incorrect information are supposed to be displayed to be fixed. However, when I run this query I get the following error:

> the stored procedure used by this report in not your database
>
> Error in Run_Report
>
> Description:Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE'

```
SELECT 
grp.customer "Customer", 
grp.customershipto "CST", 
cst.name "Name", 
cst.city "City", 
cst.territory "CST Territory",
grp.spcgroup "SPC Group",
grp.territory "SPC Group Territory",
(Case
WHEN cst.territory = 200 THEN 
      (Case WHEN cst.territory = grp.territory THEN 'Correct'
         ELSE 'Look Into' END)
ELSE
      (Case WHEN substring(grp.territory,2,3) = cst.territory THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Look Into' END)
END) "Salesman SPC Check",
(Case 
  When Sum(tgrp.spcgrp2) = 28 and cst.customertype = 'IND' THEN 'Correct'
  when Sum(tgrp.spcgrp2) = 25 and cst.customertype = 'ENG' THEN 'Correct'
  when cst.territory = 200 THEN 'Correct'
ELSE 'Look Into'
  END) "Number of SPCs",
(Case 
 WHEN cst.territory = 200 THEN ' '
ELSE 
 (Case WHEN substring(grp.territory,6,1) <> substring(grp.spcgroup,5,1) THEN 'WRONG SPC Group Territory' ELSE 'Correct' END)
END) "SPC Group Territory Check",
  (Case
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01003' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T01007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02003' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T02007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03003' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T03007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04003' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T04007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05003' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T05007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T10007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T11007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T12007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13001' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13002' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13004' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13005' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13006' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN grp.Territory = 'T13007' THEN 'Correct'
  WHEN cst.Territory = 200 THEN 'Correct'
 ELSE 'Invalid'
 END) "6 Digit SPC Group Territory", 
 grp.dateadded "Date SPC Group Added", 
 grp.useridadded "User Added", 
 grp.datemod "Date SPC Group Mod.", 
 grp.useridmod "User Mod"

From ARCustomerSHIPTOSPCGroup Grp
 Left outer Join Arcustomershipto cst on Grp.customershipto = cst.customershipto
 Left outer Join
(Select grp2.customershipto,
  Sum(Case
       When grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC01' THEN 1
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC02' THEN 2
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC03' THEN 3
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC04' THEN 4
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC05' THEN 5
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC06' THEN 6
       when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC07' THEN 7
      END) spcgrp2_sum
 From ARCustomerSHIPTOSPCGroup grp2
 Group By grp2.customershipto
) tgrp                                                                                                                                                                                        

WHERE  cst.status = 'Active'

Group by
  grp.customer, grp.customershipto, cst.name, cst.city, cst.territory,    cst.customertype, grp.spcgroup, grp.territory, grp.dateadded, grp.dateadded, grp.useridadded, grp.datemod, grp.useridmod

HAVING    NOT (   (cst.territory = 200 AND cst.territory = grp.territory)
           OR (substring (grp.territory, 2, 3) = cst.territory))
   OR NOT (   (SUM (tgrp.spcgrp2) = 28 AND cst.customertype = 'IND')
           OR (SUM (tgrp.spcgrp2) = 25 AND cst.customertype = 'ENG')
           OR (cst.territory = 200))
```

Comment: The error message says it all.  You can't use Sum() in this way.

Comment: In what way do I have to use it? I'm not good at this type of thing, so i am oblivious how to fix it.

Comment: You can replace it with a sub-query, or if you are already doing a group by you can change your WHERE to a HAVING.

Comment: Please don't remove the original problem from the question. In its current state, it will be impossible for future readers to see the problem that the answers pertain to.

Comment: I bet you have the group by in the wrong spot.  How can you expect help with code you do not post?

Comment: @Blam I have the entire code posted.

Comment: My apologies @Allen. I meant to update the question title.

Comment: No you don't.  there is not group by in the posted code

Comment: I have it after the edit

Answer (score 2):

Aggregates are computed based on `GROUP BY` statements, they tell the database which sets of rows to aggregate. In the grand scheme, this happens after the `WHERE` clause is executed. You have to filter the available rows *before* you can group them.

You haven't posted enough code for me to give you a concrete solution. But, there are two ways to avoid this problem. Use the `HAVING` clause, or use a subquery in the where clause.

The `HAVING` clause is used just like `WHERE` but it comes after `GROUP BY` in the order of processing. It can do things like, get all user types that have more than ten users over the age of 25:

```
SELECT users.type
FROM users
WHERE users.age > 25
GROUP BY users.type
HAVING count(users.id) > 10
```

Unfortunately, the way SQL was designed the order that clauses appear in a written query doesn't correspond very well to the order they are executed. This is a common source of confusion, especially when it comes to aliases. You can read more about the logical order of processing here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-lexical-vs-logical-order/.

EDIT:

I think the solution is actually much simpler. Your second outer join is where you come up with the spcgrp2 field. In the rest of the query you only use the sum of the scpgrp2 field. So, just sum it in the subquery.

Your second left outer join becomes

```
Left outer Join
    (Select grp2.customershipto,
      Sum(Case
           When grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC01' THEN 1
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC02' THEN 2
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC03' THEN 3
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC04' THEN 4
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC05' THEN 5
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC06' THEN 6
           when grp2.spcgroup = 'SPC07' THEN 7
          END) spcgrp2_sum
     From ARCustomerSHIPTOSPCGroup grp2
     Group By grp2.customershipto
    ) tgrp
```

Then you change the two lines with `Sum(tgrp.spcgrp2)` to

```
  When tgrp.spcgrp2_sum = 28 and cst.customertype = 'IND' THEN 'Correct'
  when tgrp.spcgrp2_sum = 25 and cst.customertype = 'ENG' THEN 'Correct'
```

Comment: I supplied the entire code for you to review. I am unsure exactly what you mean, however, I am going through the link you supplied.

Comment: @RichardHorvath I updated my answer with what I think is a solution. Obviously, I can't test it... so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started in the way that Tab Alleman mentioned:

```
(Case WHEN (select Sum(tgrp.spcgrp2) from tgrp) = 28 and cst.customertype = 'IND' THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Look Into' END) = 'Look Into'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't reference aggregate functions in the `WHERE` clause; that's what `HAVING` is for.

Additionally, there's rarely a good reason to use `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause. You should look into converting those into Boolean logic. I believe the following will accomplish what you're attempting:

```
WHERE  cst.status = 'Active'
--Your GROUP BY clause goes here
HAVING    NOT (   (cst.territory = 200 AND cst.territory = grp.territory)
               OR (substring (grp.territory, 2, 3) = cst.territory))
       OR NOT (   (SUM (tgrp.spcgrp2) = 28 AND cst.customertype = 'IND')
               OR (SUM (tgrp.spcgrp2) = 25 AND cst.customertype = 'ENG')
               OR (cst.territory = 200))
```

Comment: That works thanks, but now I am getting another error at the very end. It's saying there is a syntax error near the keyword group. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure?   I don't think you can have non-aggregates in a having

Comment: @Blam: You can certainly have non-aggregates in a `HAVING` clause. It's generally discouraged, because it's better to have them resolve earlier. In this case it's necessary because some of the non-aggregates need to be resolved in association with the aggregates (i.e. because of all the `OR`s).

Comment: OK then please show the required group by between the where and having

Comment: @Blam: Fair enough. I totally overlooked the need to stick the `GROUP BY` between them.